# unable to import paart-parslemouth in android

Tags: android, praat, chaquopy

i am trying to install paart-parselmouth in android but unable to install I am getting the following error

How can I install it or how can I install its tar file?

Failed to install praat-parselmouth from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/80/533a7330d7ed612628656f9aaee115076c578330039bc179c09fb8423251/praat-parselmouth-0.4.0.tar.gz.

here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.live_audio"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        sourceSets {
            main {
                python {
                    srcDirs = ["src/main/python"]
                }
            }
        }
        python {
           // buildPython "/usr/local/bin/python3"
         //   buildPython "python3"
            pip {
                install "praat-parselmouth"
                install "numpy"
                install "six"
            }


        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Chaquopy doesnt support this library on Android yet. Perhaps you could run it on a server and have your app communicate with it.

Comment: is there any other way i need to do it in real time can't use server

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way.